# Preventing Format Exception in Numeric Entry

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I use an Entry in a View with the following setting:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EntryInput}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Margin="5, 0, 5, 15" x:Name="entryControl"/>
```

Depending on the type of input, I use KeyboardSetting **Numeric** or default. The BindableProperty is as follows:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EntryInputProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryInput), typeof(string), typeof(MyInputView), default(string), BindingMode.TwoWay);
...
public string EntryInput
{
    get => (string)GetValue(EntryInputProperty);
    set => SetValue(EntryInputProperty, value);
}
```

When the View is loaded, I want to clear the Text of the Entry and set it to string.Empty (not to the default value "0" also for Numeric Entry). When I use KeyboardSetting "Numeric", I get a **System.FormatException: 'The input string '' was not in a correct format.'**

Can I prevent this in a way and still have the Entry really empty (not "0")?
Also when a user deletes all the text from the Entry the exception is thrown.

In my case, I would say it also make the UI slow when the UI is loaded.

Are there solutions for that?

==== Stacktrace of the Exception ====

```
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, ReadOnlySpan`1 value, TypeCode type)
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.TryConvert(Object& value, BindableProperty targetProperty, Type convertTo, Boolean toTarget) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindingExpression.cs:line 464
```

Comment: what is the source of the exception?

Comment: I added the Stacktrace of the Exception. The source is actually "System.Private.CoreLib" and it happens in the EntryInput-Property-Setter when this empty value is assigned with SetValue(EntryInputProperty, value);

Comment: This is on Windows (not Android emulator)? Sounds like Maui uses WinUI's NumberBox, but is missing conversion between Double.NaN and String.Empty. Empty string should internally be Double.NaN. You can report this issue at `github maui issues`. Hmm. As a test, bind it to a `double` property (instead of `string EntryInput`). Does that work? Set property to Double.NaN to clear it.

Comment: The App is running on the Android Emulator: Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33). I can't understand why it is using a NumberBox, it is just an Entry defined in XAML. Problem with the double value is that this is a view and in one usage of the View I want to have it as string and in the other one as a double so I would need a way to do this with my DataBindings. The other reason was that I want to store the values in a database and thought it might be better to do this as a string in the end when thinking of internationalization - so I stayed with string here. Using double still crashes.

Comment: I understand you need it as a string; the test with double was to determine what is going wrong in Maui. To be clear, when property is a double, the same exception happens? (if its a different message, that is a different problem, related to trying to use it sometimes as numeric, sometimes any text). I'm surprised empty string fails on Android with double; that must have been working in xamarin.forms, not sure what code has changed for Maui. All you can do is report it as an issue.

Comment: The alternative is a fair amount of work. Would write custom entry handler on each platform, to override the handling of input. I haven't tried this myself. I don't know if there is an example anywhere.

Comment: It is the same issue when using a double property. To be clear, the Exception happens, but it is not like the App crashes and is gone. I was just wondering why my ContentPage is taking so long to load and added Exceptions-Settings in VS. Don’t know if these two are related, but anyway, Exceptions don’t help in that  I can’t really understand why an empty Entry.Text is a problem when using Numeric Keyboards and why it is implemented like that then

Comment: _The alternative is a fair amount of work. Would write custom entry handler on each platform, to override the handling of input. I haven't tried this myself. I don't know if there is an example anywhere._ - @ToolmakerSteve: is there any idea how this could be done when an empty numeric value is not allowed. Here, it appears like as soon as I try to delete all the text in the numeric entry it is an empty string and is not allowed anymore. The only thing I could imagine would be a validator that just allows numeric values in the input. I'd also need to open just numeric Keyboard then

Comment: I assume it works if you have `double` property, and always a numeric Keyboard. Obviously deleting all text is a common action, so its hard to imagine that being broken, if you use Numeric the way it was designed (with `double`).

Comment: Is there a way to have a conditional binding? (Just thinking). The reason is that the entry is in my own view element and therefore could be integrated several times in a ContentPage (XAML), so I‘d need a way to bind it to a string or a double depending on the Keyboard setting. I also tried it with a double BindableProperty, but when I tried to set the Entry.Text = string.Empty (which is not right for a double Entry, but I want no Text in it) or when I deleted all the Text, I could see the Exception in Debugger when activated.

Comment: Is there a way to have a conditional binding?  Unfortunately, no. BTW, have you tried to use Entry.Text = null ?

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint! This seemed to help in this case and I marked it as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jianwei Sun - MSFT commented, I tried it with setting `Entry.Text = null` instead of setting it to `string.Empty` when I have a `Numeric` Entry. Great and thanks for this hint!